# Git ignoring add with wildcard for some files

Tags: html, git, git-add

I have a project am working on:

there I have many files, I can do something like:

```
git add *.cvs
```

and git gently add all csv files for commiting, so far so good...

but if I try to do the same with *.html files, git just ignore my commands, then I have to add those one by one by the name

Why?

Comment: Are these HTML files at the same level from which you ran `git add *.html`?  If so, then it should have worked.  Maybe you can clarify where these HTML files are located.

Comment: ohh, that could be the reason, since the html files are in child folders

Comment: Just add the wildcard at each level, this always works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting the pathspec like this:

`git add "*.html"`

The reason behind it is that shell expands the wildcard before git.